# can i add different itemStyle on each node so each node have different color on radar echarts?

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, echarts

i found an example in this link https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.data.itemStyle where you can add different color on each symbol. However when im trying to implement on my case it seems that its not supported. Am i doing something wrong or indeed its not supported in this type of graph? Is there any way around to add a different color on each node? i tryed to add a function on 'symbol', but it only accepts string so its impossible.

Basically this is what i want to achivie but using radar chart.

this is what im asking:

[image]

[image]

the code for the chart above is:

```
    option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: "category",
    data: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [{
    data: [{
      value: 820,
      itemStyle: {
        color: "rgba(16, 198, 80, 1)"
      }
    }, {
      value: 820,
      itemStyle: {
        color: "rgba(13, 255, 0, 1)"
      }
    }, {
      value: 820,
      itemStyle: {
        color: "blue"
      }
    }, {
      value: 820,
      itemStyle: {
        color: "black"
      }
    }, {
      value: 820,
      itemStyle: {
        color: "purple"
      }
    }, 1330, 1320],
    type: "line",
    itemStyle: {
      color: "rgba(225, 55, 55, 1)"
    }
  }]
}
```

Here's my code:

```
this.options = {
  radar: {
    // shape: 'circle',
    indicator: [
      { name: `Sales`, max: 6500 },
      { name: 'Administration', max: 16000 },
      { name: 'Information Technology', max: 30000 },
      { name: 'Customer Support', max: 38000 },
      { name: 'Development', max: 52000 },
      { name: 'Marketing', max: 25000 },
    ],
    triggerEvent: true,
    name: {
      formatter: function (params: any) {
        // console.log(params);
        return params as string;
      },
    },
    axisLine: {},
    splitArea: {
      show: false,
    },
  },

  series: [
    {
      type: 'radar',

      symbolSize: 10,

      data: [
        {
          value: [
            {
              value: 4200,
              itemStyle: {
                color: 'rgba(16, 198, 80, 1)',
              },
            },
            3000,
            20000,
            35000,
            50000,
            18000,
          ],
          areaStyle: {
            normal: {
              color: new graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
                {
                  offset: 0,
                  color: 'rgba(176,196,222, 0.3)',
                },
                {
                  offset: 1,
                  color: 'rgba(176,196,222, 1)',
                },
              ]),
            },
            emphasis: {
              color: new graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
                { offset: 0, color: '#2c2c2c54' },
                { offset: 0.7, color: '#2c2c2c54' },
                { offset: 1, color: '#2c2c2c7a' },
              ]),
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      tooltip: {},

      lineStyle: {
        color: 'rgba(96, 125, 139, 1)',
        width: 3,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have them in different colors, but it seems like your options is not following the correct data type. Reading [radar series data type docs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-radar.data), you can notice that data is an array of object, those object represent your entries, each entry has an array of values, an item style, and an area style and a lot more already mentioned in the documentation, your mistake is nesting the value in the series, value : { value ?? }.
below is an example of what you should do.

```
option={
  radar: {
    indicator: [
      {
        name: `Sales`,
        max: 10
      },
      {
        name: 'Administration',
        max: 10
      },
      {
        name: 'Information Technology',
        max: 10
      },
      {
        name: 'Customer Support',
        max: 10
      },
      {
        name: 'Development',
        max: 10
      },
      {
        name: 'Marketing',
        max: 10
      },
      
    ],
    
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: "radar",
      data: [
        {
          value: [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ],
          itemStyle: {
            color: 'red'
          },
          areaStyle: {
            color: 'red'
          }
        },
        {
          value: [
            4,
            5,
            6
          ],
          areaStyle: {
            color: 'purple'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: this is the output -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-echarts-p1fabx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

However, i dont want to color the area and create multiple areas, i only want to have diferrent colors on each node

Comment: A radar chart supposed to help visualizing multivariate data, if you care about one single node of a multivariate set, then, I am guessing a radar chart isn't what you should be using.

Comment: i showed exactly an example of what i want to achieve

Comment: Yes I understood what you are trying to achieve, for me it doesn't fit a radar chart usage, as far as my knowledge goes